# Bash - execute something if a value is present in yaml file

Tags: bash, yaml, conditional-statements, key

file.yaml contains

```
thatyamlkey:
  - key1
  - key2
  - key3
```

I would like to check if "key2" exists in "thatyamlkey:". If it does, execute something, if not exit 1.

How would I go about this in bash.

This file is accessible via a linux like /path/to/file.yaml or a http://path/to/file.yaml

Spark an idea, please :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use a tool like `yq` (which is a YAML parser wrapped around `jq`):

```
filter='.thatyamlkey | any(. == $ARGS.positional[0])'
yq -e "$filter" file.yaml --args key2 > /dev/null || exit 1

...
```

`yq` does not make HTTP requests; you'll have to use a tool like `curl` to fetch a URL first.

Comment: Repository and how to install: `https://github.com/mikefarah/yq`